# Concatenar o campo e agrupar o restante

Tags: php, sql, html5, sql-server

Possuo a seguinte query:

```
SELECT finempe.data_empenho
       , finempe.num_empenho
       , finhisem.quantidade
       , finhisem.historico
       , finhisem.valor
       , finhisem.valor_total
FROM finempe
RIGHT JOIN finhisem ON
    (finhisem.num_empenho = finempe.num_empenho)
WHERE finempe.data_empenho between '01-01-2002' and '31-12-2002' and  finempe.valor_empenhado != finempe.valor_anulado and finempe.codigo_tipo = 1 and finhisem.codigo_tipo = 1 and conta_desp = 31900100 and finhisem.ano_empenho = 2002
ORDER BY finempe.num_empenho, finhisem.num_seq
```

Desejo agrupar as linhas, porém concatenando o campo *historico* (Imagino fazer um SUM no *valor* e *valor-total* e uma concatenação no *historico*)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo agrupando linha 5, 6 e 7:
"2002-01-02" "45" "10000" "Provisao de recursos p/pagto. complementar aos servidores aposentados vinculados ao FUNCAPI, p/ o periodo de janeiro a dezembro/2002" "540000" "540000"

ou seja, manter todos os valores e concatenar o histórico

Comment: Olá! O que já tentou fazer até o momento?

Comment: Complete a pergunta dizendo quais campos quer agrupar. Coloque um exemplo de como seria o resultado esperado e também coloque alguma tentativa que você já fez e não funcionou como o esperado.

Comment: O que você quer concatenar no campo historico?

Comment: @WellingtonAraujo quero concatenar o campo historico da linha 1 com o da linha 2 e manter o restante como se fosse um group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei resolvendo o problema através do PHP, como iria exibir em uma tabela num browser conseguir utilizar umas artemanhas, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
                                       $linha = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado);

                                       $data = date_format($linha["data_empenho"], 'd/m/y');
                                       $num_empenho_ant = $num_empenho = $linha["num_empenho"];
                                       $historico = $linha["historico"];
                                       $quantidade = $linha["quantidade"];
                                       $unidade = $linha["unidade"];
                                       $valor = $linha["valor"];
                                       $valor_anulado += $linha["valor_anulado"];
                                       $valor_total = $linha["valor_total"];
                                       $total = $linha["valor_total"];

                                        while ($linha)//COLOCA OS VALORES EM VARIÁVEIS (QUANDO "num_empenho" for diferente) PARA PERMITIR A CONCATENAÇÃO DO HISTORICO E IMPRIMO-LO COMPLETO (QUANDO "num_empenho" for igual)
                                        {
                                            if($linha["num_empenho"] == $num_empenho_ant)
                                            {                                               
                                               $historico .=  " ".$linha["historico"];        

                                            }
                                            else{  
                                                ?>
                                                <tr class="odd gradeA">                                                    
                                                        <td align = "right">  <?php echo $data; ?> </td>                                                    
                                                        <td align = "center"> <?php echo $num_empenho; ?> </td>
                                                        <td align = "center"> <?php echo $unidade; ?> </td>
                                                        <td align = "center"> <?php echo $unidade; ?> </td>
                                                        <td align = "center"> <?php echo $historico; ?> </td>
                                                        <td align = "right">  <?php echo number_format($valor, 2, ',', '.');?> </td>
                                                        <td align = "right">  <?php echo number_format($valor_total, 2, ',', '.');?> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                   <?php        
                                                $num_empenho_ant = $linha["num_empenho"];                                                

                                                $data = date_format($linha["data_empenho"], 'd/m/y');
                                                $num_empenho = $linha["num_empenho"];
                                                $historico = $linha["historico"];
                                                $quantidade = $linha["quantidade"];
                                                $unidade = $linha["unidade"];                                                
                                                $valor = $linha["valor"];
                                                $valor_total = $linha["valor_total"];
                                                $total += $linha["valor_total"];
                                                $valor_anulado += $linha["valor_anulado"];

                                               }

                                               $linha = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado);
                                        }
```

Comment: Top... é basicamente a lógica que usei.... mandei em SQL porque vc pediu em SQL....

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, tive que usar um "while" pra fazer o que você precisa. Usei um esquema do sql chamado "CURSOR". Segue o exemplo, executa ai e me fala se deu certo:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#DadosTeste') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DadosTeste
CREATE TABLE #DadosTeste(data_empenho datetime, num_empenho int, quantidade int, historico varchar(800), valor varchar(800), valor_total varchar(800))

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#DadosHisto') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DadosHisto
CREATE TABLE #DadosHisto(num_empenho int, histor varchar(800))

insert #DadosTeste values('2002-01-02', 37, 1000, 'TESTE DE TESTE DE TESTE', '1208200','1208200')
insert #DadosTeste values('2002-01-02', 37, 0, '2002', '0','0')

insert #DadosTeste values('2002-01-02', 38, 1000, 'TESTE PARA QUALQUER COISA', '900000','900000')
insert #DadosTeste values('2002-01-02', 38, 0, 'ANO 2002', '0','0')

insert #DadosTeste values('2002-01-02', 45, 1000, 'VAMOS QUE VAMOS', '540000','540000')
insert #DadosTeste values('2002-01-02', 45, 0, 'FUNDACAO DO TESTE', '0','0')

DECLARE @NUMG_EMPENHO INT
DECLARE @HISTORICO VARCHAR(800)

DECLARE CUR_Cartoes CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 
        num_empenho
        ,historico
    FROM 
        #DadosTeste

open CUR_Cartoes

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_Cartoes INTO @NUMG_EMPENHO, @HISTORICO

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN

    if exists(SELECT num_empenho FROM #DadosHisto where num_empenho = @NUMG_EMPENHO) BEGIN
        UPDATE #DadosHisto SET histor = (SELECT histor FROM #DadosHisto where num_empenho = @NUMG_EMPENHO) + ' ' + @HISTORICO WHERE num_empenho = @NUMG_EMPENHO
    END ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT #DadosHisto VALUES(@NUMG_EMPENHO, @HISTORICO)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_Cartoes INTO @NUMG_EMPENHO, @HISTORICO

END

CLOSE CUR_Cartoes
DEALLOCATE CUR_Cartoes

SELECT 
    TE.data_empenho
    ,DA.num_empenho
    ,TE.quantidade
    ,DA.histor
    ,TE.valor
    ,TE.valor_total 
FROM 
    #DadosHisto DA
    INNER JOIN #DadosTeste TE ON DA.num_empenho = TE.num_empenho
WHERE
    TE.valor <> '0'
```

Comment: vc modifica o BD "juntando" o campo histórico e depois faz um select simples?

Comment: Fiz o seguinte, criei uma temporária, depois dentro do "While" fui incluindo nessa temporária os dados da coluna "Historico" e concatenando,  e por fim faço um "inner" com a tabela original mostrando o resultado.